# Short story about researchers on a strange planet, genetic mutation

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this short story in a scifi collection a number of years ago. I think it was the title story.

A small group of between five and ten people (researchers, scientists, colonists) are (I think) cryogenically frozen and arrive on a planet with very strange life. Trees the size of skyscrapers weird animals, etc. The people live in their space ship and over many years they have genetic mutations and I think some of them die. I think there's also at least one more generation and they become more and more like the strange life on the planet.

I thought the title was "The Eternal Golden Braid", but that's the subtitle of Godel Escher Bach, so Googling is useless. I'm pretty sure it's something like that though.

There's another story in the same collection about a little golden flying saucer that comes to a man in a park and no one believes him and he goes crazy or something.

Comment: The second story sounds a bit like [*A Saucer of Loneliness,*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Saucer_of_Loneliness) a short story by Theodore Sturgeon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks Joe L., you are right. The short story and eponymous collection (in which *A Saucer of Loneliness* also appears) is Theodore Sturgeon's [The Golden Helix](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?40819) (1979).

Comment: I don't think ["A Saucer of Loneliness"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?37301) appears in the collection [*The Golden Helix*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?40819).

Comment: Huh that's curious. Maybe I just them both around the same time.